# Jetty 6 - QueuedThreadPool versus ThreadPool

Tags: optimization, configuration, jetty

I am using Jetty 6 and was wondering when the QueuedThreadPool should be used over the ThreadPool?  By default, Jetty 6 comes configured with the QueuedThreadPool.

My server has Java 6 installed so I was thinking that I should use the ThreadPool:

```
<New class="org.mortbay.thread.QueuedThreadPool">
            <Set name="minThreads">10</Set>
            <Set name="maxThreads">200</Set>
            <Set name="lowThreads">20</Set>
            <Set name="SpawnOrShrinkAt">2</Set>
        </New>

<New class="org.mortbay.thread.concurrent.ThreadPool">
            <Set name="corePoolSize">50</Set>
            <Set name="maximumPoolSize">50</Set>
        </New>
```

Thanks,
Walter